# Possible to set local folder for automatic file uploads

Tags: browser

Bit of a loose question so if it gets marked down I'll remove it.. but..

I'm using Primefaces/Spring/Hibernate for Java server.

My application knows a load of file names I need to upload. Those files are on my local computer. Is it possible to tell the application the root directory of these files, for it to then setup uploads for each of these files without me needing to browse for each file individually?

I assume this is a browser security issue, i.e. the user needs to explicitly state which file the application is allowed to know about etc?

If not I'll have to do it in a local application but I was hoping there was a way a mass upload could be kicked off from the browser by just setting the local directory of the files.

Comment: _"I assume this is a browser security issue, i.e. the user needs to explicitly state which file the application is allowed to know about etc? "_ Correct (as can he read in several other stackoverflow posts)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the Primefaces uploader, upload all the files in the directory and let the application sort them out once it has them on the server.